# Consistent versioning in Python project

Tags: python, version, project, distutils, python-sphinx

I have a Python project which has Sphinx documentation and distutils for publishing to Pip.

Both of these functions require a version (e.g., 0.4b3)

Is there a best practice for automatically maintaining a consistent version number across the various utilities which require version numbers?

As a bonus, is there anything that integrates with git (e.g., via tags)?

Comment: You could migrate this topic to programmers.stackexchange.com, this feels more suitable for that site.

Answer (score 1):

This is a favorite question on Python distutils mailing lists.  You can import your module from setup.py as well as from conf.py and get module.**version**.  This may not work depending on your imports, your use of 2to3 or other factors, in which case you can move your version to a text file and open that from your module, setup.py and conf.py.

My personal take on this is that it’s no great burden to update the version number in three places.  It’s a minor step in the release process.

Answer (score 0):

This is an untested answer, but I imagine this would be pretty easy to do with sphinx in the `conf.py` script. As this script is just Python, you could do something like this:

```
import subprocess

...

path_to_source = "../src"
release = subprocess.check_output(["git", "rev-parse", "HEAD"], cwd=path_to_source)
version = subprocess.check_output(["git", "describe", "--tags", "HEAD"], cwd=path_to_source)
```

Naturally, you might want to do some string processing on the output of the commands to get them as you want them, and some error checking, but the basic idea should hold.

As I say, I haven't tested this, so I could be entirely wrong, so do tell me if you find a problem with this idea.

Comment: Thanks for the snippet, but to be clear, I was looking for any practices already in use, rather than trying to roll my own.